# setting a vertical highlighted line off in vim

Tags: macos, unix, vim, macros, highlight

I am seeing a vertical highlighted line. It is independent of any syntax used. How can I remove it?

My  ~/.vimrc is simple:

```
syntax on
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set expandtab
```

This in a macOS-Mojave (10.14.6)

The line looks like this:
[image: vim highlighted vertical line]

Comment: Add `set colorcolumn=` to .vimrc, maybe some plugin introduces this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the `colorcolumn`. Some people like it because it helps them keep their line length under some number of characters.

You can remove it by setting it to nothing, like `set colorcolumn=` or just `set cc=`.

If it turns out you do want that functionality, you can add more lines (`set colorcolumn=80,120,140`) or change the color of the lines (`highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=7 guibg=lightgrey`), where the number specified in `ctermbg` corresponds to the [colors listed here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#8-bit).

Comment: I’ve had a lot of fun with `set colorcolumn=+0`, so it automatically adjusts to the value of `textwidth`